# How to get same memory usage as displayed in Activity Monitor

Tags: bash, macos, shell, swift3

When i use "top" to show memory usage is not the same as in Activity Monitor. So how to get the same amount of free/used memory as in Activity Monitor programmatically ?

[top and acitivty monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UhWU.png)

Comment: i use swift 3 in my program and if you know how to get the info with "top" or without "top" with swift 3 i want to know that.

Answer (score -2):

You may also use htop. It's much easier to understand if you want to monitor memory usage and load average.

Comment: i want to distribute my app so it need to be preinstalled with the OS

Comment: What's your linux distro? Also, what do you mean by "distribute my app"? Are you going to deploy it remotely for multiple clients or monitor each? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: its on osx (see the picture and tag). and no i want to do it in local

Comment: Try: 
**top -F -R -o mem**

"top" would be best to use if you don't want to install other package like htop. Also, you can change mem to cpu, vsize, rsize depends on what field you want.

Comment: i know how to get memory usage ,its not the problem I just want the exactly same amount as shown in Acitivy Monitor. But  thx anyway